# MessageSummaryItems.Id vs MessageSummaryItems.Envelope.MessageId vs MessageId.GMailMessageId vs MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId

Tags: mailkit

I am using MailKit to retrive emails from a Gmail account. However, I have been confused about the Id of an email.

I already looked at the documentation but could not find a complete explanation.

For example, I noticed `UniqueId`, is actually not unique; I mean if I move an email to a particular folder and fetch that email it has an Id (say 1). Then if I remove that email from the folder and add it again to the folder it gets andother UniqueId (e.g., 2)!

When I try to get `MessageSummaryItems.Id` the value for my emails are null.

The value for `MessageSummaryItems.GMailMessageId` is a big number that I don't know if it is realy uniquely assigned to that email.

The value for `MessageSummaryItems.Envelope.MessageId` seems a globally unique Id for that email.

I want more explanation about these Ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail does not support the `OBJECTID` extension, so `MessageSummaryItems.Id` will never get anything (e.g. the returned `IMessageSummary.Id` will always be `null`).

`MessageSummaryItems.Envelope.MessageId` is the `Message-Id` header value.

`MessageSummaryItems.GMailMessageId` is a GMail-specific identifier that is similar to the `UniqueId` but is globally unique for your account.

A `UniqueId` is a unique identifier, but is folder-specific. In other words, a message with a `UniqueId` of `5` in your `INBOX` folder will be different from the message with a `UniqueId` of `5` in your `Starred` folder, for example.

However, on GMail, a message in your `INBOX` with a `GMailMessageId` of `5` will be identical to a message in your `Starred` folder with the same `GMailMessageId`. They will both refer to the exact same message.

To understand why this is, GMail really only has 1 folder (`All Mail`) where *all* of your messages are located. All of your other folders, including `INBOX`, `Drafts`, `Sent`, etc. are just virtual views of the `All Mail` folder that filter out all messages that do not have the corresponding GMail `Label`.

That's why if you add a label to a group of messages, they will show up in your `INBOX` and in a new folder that gets created that matches the name of the label that you just created.

Comment: Thanks @jstedfast for the complete description. Maybe it is worth to add it more explicitly into the documentation.